# Django Rest Framework for nested serializer for POST method json format output (already removed read-only)

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, jsonresponse

I want to create an application regarding student-class attendance in a simplified format like this. I am getting actual output response what I need in **GET** request like this.

```html
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "present": "Yes",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 2,
            "schedule_date": "2019-02-28",
            "start_time": "2019-02-28T11:00:00Z",
            "end_time": "2019-02-28T11:45:00Z",
            "description": "new schedule",
            "class_name": 2,
            "class_room": 1,
            "subject": 2,
            "teacher": 3
        },
        "student": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "student",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "rakhi",
            "last_name": "sawant"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "present": "No",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 2,
            "schedule_date": "2019-02-28",
            "start_time": "2019-02-28T11:00:00Z",
            "end_time": "2019-02-28T11:45:00Z",
            "description": "new schedule",
            "class_name": 2,
            "class_room": 1,
            "subject": 2,
            "teacher": 3
        },
        "student": {
            "id": 5,
            "username": "roshanritik",
            "email": "ritik@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "Ritik",
            "last_name": "Roshan"
        }
    }
]
```

but in case of **POST** request I m not getting what I actually need for the format. I have given the input request like this

```html
{
 "present" : "Yes",
 "student" : {
  "id" : 1
 },
 "schedule" :{
  "id" : 2
 }
}
```

and wants the output of the POST same like GET Response out as stated above.

This is my Model.py

```html
class Schedule(models.Model):
    schedule_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(ClassName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_room = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

```html
# Student's Attendance Table

class Attendance(models.Model):
    present = EnumField(choices=['Yes', 'No'])
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.present

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('student', 'schedule')
```

serializer.py

```html
class AttendanceSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    schedule = ScheduleSerializers(many=False, required=False)
    student = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False)

   
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ('id', 'present', 'schedule', 'student')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            schedule_data = validated_data.pop('schedule')
            schedule = SchedulePartialSerializers.create(SchedulePartialSerializers(), validated_data=schedule_data)

            student_data = validated_data.pop('student')
            student = UserPartialSerializers.create(UserPartialSerializers(), validated_data=student_data)

            attendance, created = Attendance.objects.update_or_create(schedule=schedule,  student=student,
                                                                    present=validated_data.pop('present'))
            return attendance
```

Views.py

```html
class AttendanceView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Attendance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendanceSerializers

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        write_serializer = AttendanceSerializers(data=request.data)
        write_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        instance = self.perform_create(write_serializer)

        read_serializer = AttendanceSerializers(instance)

        return Response(read_serializer.data)
```

**userserializer**

```html
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name')
```

**ScheduleSerializer**

```html
class ScheduleSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = "__all__"
```

*Please check and review code. It will be helpful.*

Comment: What do `ScheduleSerializers` and `UserSerializer` look like ?

Comment: Updated, go through nested serializers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have changed some of the code like in Model.py

```js
class Attendance(models.Model):
    present = EnumField(choices=['Yes', 'No'])
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.present
```

In Serializer.py

```js
class ScheduleSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = "__all__"


class UserPartialSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name')


class AttendanceSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = '__all__'


class AttendanceScheduleSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    schedule = ScheduleSerializers(many=False)
    student = UserSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ('id', 'present', 'schedule', 'student',)
```

The Most Need things is View.py
where actual data is being serialized by the required format which actually we wanted

```js
class AttendanceView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        a_list = Attendance.objects.all()
        serializer = AttendanceScheduleSerializers(a_list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        present = request.data.get("present")
        schedule = request.data['schedule']['id']
        student = request.data['student']['id']
        data = {'student': student, 'schedule': schedule, 'present': present}
        serializer = AttendanceSerializers(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Following in Views.py need to import above

```js
from api.serializers import UserSerializer,AttendanceSerializer, ScheduleSerializer, AttendanceScheduleSerializer
```

***Finally got the output***

Comment: Resulted got the answer which I need for Post response same like Get method